# On Riemannian geodesics

Tags: riemannian-geometry, geodesic

I am trying to understand Riemannian geometry from the book "Riemannian Manifolds: An Introduction to Curvature" by John Lee. I have the following doubt.

A Riemannian geodesic on a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ is a smooth curve $\gamma:I\to M$ such that $D_t\dot{\gamma}\equiv 0.$ Lee shows that the "geodesics of the unit sphere $S^n$ are precisely the great circles, with constant speed parametrization". Lee's argument is the following. Consider the north pole $N\in S^n$ and the tangent vector $\partial/\partial x^1$. Then it is enough to find out geodesic with initial point $N$ and initial velocity $\partial/\partial x^1$. All other geodesics can be obtained by the isotropic and transitive action on $S^n$ by the orthogonal group. First claim is that $\gamma(I)\subseteq\{(x^i)_{i=1}^n:\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}{x^i}^2=1,x^2=x^3\dots=x^n=0\}.$ Since the map $\phi(x^1,\dots,x^{n+1})\mapsto (x^1,\dots,-x^{i},\dots,x^{n+1})$ is a Riemannian isometry, and $\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}\phi\circ\gamma=\partial/\partial x^1$ and $\phi((\gamma(0)))=N$, we must have that $\phi\circ\gamma$ s again a geodesic and by uniqueness, we must have that $\gamma=\phi\circ\gamma.$ This shows that $\gamma(I)\subseteq\{(x^i)_{i=1}^n:\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}{x^i}^2=1,x^2=x^3\dots=x^{n+1}=0\}.$ Now Let me take a constant speed parametrization of $\{(x^i)_{i=1}^n:\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}{x^i}^2=1,x^2=x^3\dots=x^n=0\}$. How can I show that it has to be geodesic? The same type of reasoning from hyperboloid model tells that if we consider the hyperboloid $\{(\zeta^1,\dots,\zeta^n,\tau):\tau>0,\tau^2-\sum_{i=1}^n{\zeta^i}^2=R^2\}$ then consider the north pole $N$ again and consider the vector $\partial/\partial\zeta^1$ at $N.$ One can show again the corresponding geodesic in the hyperbolic space will stay on $\zeta^2=\zeta^3=\dots=\zeta^n=0$. Now again we can parametrize by unit speed curve. But how can we show that it has to be the geodesic?

Comment: You can find some informations about this in my answer to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3903088/derivation-of-geodesic-on-m-sphere-gamma-mathbbr-rightarrow-sm-is-gi/3903175#3903175). The idea is that the second order derivative of this parametrisation is normal to the sphere, hence its projection on the tangent space of the sphere is zero, and the constant speed parametrisation is a geodesic

Comment: @Dldier. What about the hyperbolic space?

Comment: @DIdier_'s (very nice) answer, both parts, works just as well for the hyperboloid model with very little change.

Comment: @Abeginnermathmatician The Lorentz metric on the Minkowski space being flat, its Levi-Civita connexion is the same as for the euclidean one: the argument is thus the same.