# Prove that the geodesic between two points A and B on a spherical surface is found on the curve formed by the intersection with the plane

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, geodesic, euler-lagrange-equation

Prove that the geodesic between two points A and B on a spherical surface with center O, is found
on the curve formed by the intersection of this surface with the plane passing through points A, B and either.I was supposed to use the euler-lagrange equation to show that it is a minimun, so I tried to parameterize the intersection of the plane with a generical sphere but after this process I got stuck. Could anyone help me ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hamilton's principle and the sphere, finding circles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4532576/hamiltons-principle-and-the-sphere-finding-circles)

Comment: Oh, yes! Thank you

Comment: For cultural reason, let me mention that there is a [geometric method](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3903088/788724), using only symmetries (and no computation), that ensure that geodesics of the sphere are the great circles.