# Geodesics in hyperboloid model of hyperbolic space

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, geodesic

What is the proof of

$$\gamma_{\mathbf{x} \rightarrow \mathbf{u}}(t) = \cosh(t)\mathbf{x} + \sinh(t)\mathbf{u}$$

being the formula for a geodesic on the hyperboloid model of hyperbolic space? I haven't been able to find a source that makes it clear. It seems that always the sinh and cosh come out of nowhere so I am just trying to understand how they follow from the definition of the hyperboloid.

Comment: Out of nowhere? How do you parametrize one component of the hyperbola $x^2-y^2=1$?

Comment: Makes sense, I didn't know that is how cosh and tanh are defined. So we know that cosh^2(t) - sinh^2(t) = 1.

Answer (score 1):

Let $B$ be the [Minkowski bilinear form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperboloid_model#Minkowski_quadratic_form) and assume that $x$ and $u$ satisfy
\begin{align*}
B(x,x) &= -1\\
B(u,u) &= 1\\
B(x,u) &= B(u,x) = 0
\end{align*}
A curve that lies in intersection of the hyperboloid with the $2$-plane spanned by $x$ and $u$ is of the form
$$ c(t) = a(t)x + b(t)u, $$
where
\begin{align*}
-1 &= B(c(t),c(t)).
\end{align*}
Observe that the velocity of $c$ is always space-like. The curve has unit speed with respect to the Minkowski metric, if
\begin{align*}
 1 &= B(c'(t), c'(t)).
\end{align*}
I'll leave as an exercise the proof that the unique solution to the equations above that also satisfies $c(0)=x$ and $c'(0)=u$ is
\begin{align*}
c(t) = x\cosh t + u\sinh t.
\end{align*}

Comment: For OP: these computations are the exact analogue of that on the sphere, with the only difference being in solving $a(t)^2-b(t)^2=1$ instead of $a(t)^2+b(t)^2=1$

Comment: @Didier, good point!

Comment: Okay I understand the conditions and how it is similar to the spherical case, it makes a lot more sense now. But I still don't see how we would come to the solution. Can you clarify?

Comment: @bp2021 The second part of [this old answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3903088/derivation-of-geodesic-on-m-sphere-gamma-mathbbr-rightarrow-sm-is-gi/3903175#3903175) might be useful: just change $\Bbb R^{m+1}$ with the Minkowski space, $S^m$ with the hyperboloid, $\cos$ by $\cosh$, etc. Here, show that the reflection across a vertical plane induces an isometry of the hyperbolic space, and hence the geodesic you are looking for will lie into the intersection... which is an hyperbola

Comment: Deane, from his more recent question,   the paper  being read is https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper_files/paper/2019/file/0415740eaa4d9decbc8da001d3fd805f-Paper.pdf    which  refers, for background,  to  https://people.math.wisc.edu/~jwrobbin/Do_Carmo/diffgeo.pdf  I have been trying to find out if the OP can exponentiate a square matrix, as a

Comment: I suggest reading *all* of @Didier's old answer and translating it to the hyperbolic case.

Comment: Didier your other answer helps, thanks. @Will Jagy I don't see how this relates to exponentiating a square matrix? I have looked at that source and but as far as I can tell it just states the geodesic formula. Anyway with the constructive proof it makes sense to me now.